# Unable to view or change ranges in symbology tab (Quantities)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.5

Using ArcMap 10.5, I joined data to my shapefile, when I go to the symbology tab, then quantities and select the field value, not values appear in the range and I am unable to modify or select the class number.

Here is a screen shot

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample of your data tables - your shapefile and joined table separately and joined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this issue previous, even though you haven't posted a screen shot of your attribute table. I would most certainly think that the issue is in your values within the field you are trying to symbolize. If you look in the range window, there are no values appearing, but you are able to select the field.

One of two things come to mind about what may be the issue.

1. The values in the field are not displaying properly, most likely null values.
2. If you preformed a join, you may have not joined the table properly to the shapefile. At times you may join data, however if you didn't choose the appropriate fields you may have the result you are dealing with, also null values.

Either way, the behavior displayed here, appears to be a result of null values.

You could also read up on these two sources for other examples, [Field not diplaying in Quantities Symbology](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/94230) and [Symbology on null value](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/52180)

Answer (score 3):

Another problem occuring with Symbology -> Quantities is the format of the data to be displayed. What data type is the joined data? It should be a numeric type, that is to say Short Integer, Long Integer, Float or Double.

Comment: It turned out that I didn't join properly it resulted in null values.